# How to do unequal auto margins

Tags: css, margin

folks! I'm tweaking [this Wikipedia skin file](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usuario%3aNaBUru38/common.css), so the content of all pages I see get centered with a fixed width. I've done it as well as it's possible, I think. (It only works in my account, since it's my file. You can try it in yours, of course.)

Since I use `margin: 0 auto`, the left and right margins have the same size. I don't want that, because the text appears slightly moved to the right (the div doesn't include the left bar). Rather than writing a whole new skin, let's do it the cheap way: I want to set the margins to 40% the left and 60% the right.

Now, I can't use fixed (`25px`) or relative (`40%`) margins, because then the margins would appear even when the browser window is narrower than 750px (plus the left bar).

So, I want the margins to be unequal 60% / 40%, but still automatic. Is that possible with CSS? Thanks!

Comment: I meant to write "Hi, folks!", but the editor doesn't seem to save. Sorry!

Comment: position:relative;
margin-left:60%;
margin-right:40%;
margin:0 auto;

Comment: It doesn't work. It seems that the "margin:0 auto" overrides the previous "margin-left:60%; margin-right:40%". Any other ideas?

Comment: try margin-right: 8%; margin-left: 5% without using any padding, adjust on your taste.

Comment: As I said, that doesn't work exactly as I'd like, because the margins would appear even when the browser window is narrow. That's why I wanted some sort of auto margins. Anyway, with the regular maximised window, that system does center the text in the middle of the screen. Thanks and good luck!